# Wordpress: nav_menu doesn't appear in homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have a small problem with nav_menu that is not appear in my homepage after I created a new custom post types.

This is code that i put it in my functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'create_companies_type');
    function create_companies_type(){
    register_post_type('information', array(
     'label' => __('Nos informations'),
     'singular_label' => __('information'),
     'public' => true,
     'show_ui' => true,
     'capability_type' => 'post',
     'hierarchical' => false,
     'supports' => array('title', 'author', 'thumbnail','editor','custom-fields'),
    ));
}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

  function my_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( is_home())
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'information','post') );

  return $query;
}
```

If you can help me I'll really grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the post type showing up in you custom menu area, then it is there. I am just taking a guess at what you mean though.

Comment: Thanks, Mr for your quick answer! but it's not my problem.
my problem is that my default menu doesn't appear in the home page